# SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: unity, c#, socket

I am working on connecting a client to a server using socket connection. I have a button, when I click on the button, it's giving the below exception in Unity.

**"SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."**.

What will be the issue? Can anyboady help me out? Below is the code I have written for connecting to the server:

```
internal Boolean socketReady = false;
NetworkStream theStream; 
StreamWriter writer; 
StreamReader reader; 
try{
        connect = new TcpClient (host, port);
        theStream = connect.GetStream ();
        writer = new StreamWriter (theStream);
        reader = new StreamReader (theStream);
        return true;
        //socketReady = true;
    }
    catch(ObjectDisposedException) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the Server code available as well?

Comment: You need to debug your server.  More than likely there is a router blocking the port.  You need to configure your server properly.  This is not a coding problem or a game development based question and I am voting to close this question.

Comment: @hobnob : Iam using an SocketTest application to test it

Comment: I'd suggest then that your Firewall is blocking you connection. Have you tried opening port 1234 manually to see whether that fixes the issue? This issue arises when the server isn't accepting a connection, which suggests either that the firewall is blocking the request, or that the application you're using as a server isn't listening correctly

Comment: @hobnob : how can I solve this issue.

Comment: He told you to open the port. So open the port.

Comment: I opened the port.But still its giving an error.whether I need to restart my system after opening the port

Comment: If the port is open then the only other issue I can see will be with your server test software. It's important to understand that the problem here doesn't appear to be Unity, or your C# code, but appears instead to be with the server part. You can test this by installing telnet (if you're using Windows, Mac and Linux come with it already), opening a command line, and then typing: `telnet localhost 1234`... if that fails to open a connection then it's definitely the server. If that's the case then there's really not much more we can do to help, as this is a software issue rather than coding

Comment: Rather than trying some random code\app you found on the net why don't you start with the MSDN samples, download the sample code and see how the tcp\udp client\server samples work

Answer (score 1):

The target machine actively refusing the connection means that no one is listening on that port, so the target machine refused the connection.

You'll need to verify that the server software you are trying to run is actually running and accepting connections.

Comment: I have used the port as "1234".

Comment: Yes, that's just a number. Do you have a server running there?

Comment: yes.I have used http://sockettest.sourceforge.net/ as the server for testing